# Bluebird: getting the results of each()

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Here's something I don't understand about `.each()`. The function returns a promise that yields the original array instead of an array of results from the callback. How you get the results then? `.map()` isn't what I'm looking for since the elements need to be processed in order.

```
var input = [1, 2, 3];
return promise.each(input, causeSideEffect).then(function() {
    /* return true if any side effect occurred */
});
```

In the example, `causeSideEffect()` returns a promise of a boolean, indicating whether it did anything.

EDIT: A shim that yield the version 3.0 behavior

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var testInput = [ 1 ];
promise.each(testInput, function(){}).then(function(results) {
    if (results[0] === 1) {
        var originalFunction = promise.each;
        promise.each = function(array, callback) {
            var results = [];
            var closure = function(item, index, length) {
                return promise.resolve(callback(item, index, length)).then(results.push.bind(results));
            };
            return originalFunction(array, closure).return(results);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We agree with you. In fact we agree with you so much that this behaviour changes in 3.0 (where 3.0 will return the modified array).

Basically, `.each` was not anticipated to be used this way - it was expected that people will use `.each` only for side effects and not for things they'd use `.map` for.

Until then, you can either do the accumulation yourself:

```
var input = [1, 2, 3], result = [];
return promise.each(input, causeSideEffect).then(function() {
    result.push(modificationHappened); // true or false
}).then(function(){
    // access result
});
```

Or use `.reduce` and accumulate the result into an array (Example in the docs).

Comment: Cool. Will 3.0 be released pretty soon?

Comment: @cleong petka is super busy with io.js stuff but we hope that it's a matter of weeks.