# Bluebird nested promises with each/spread

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm facing an issue while using bluebird Promises. I'm using CoffeeScript but JavaScript answers are welcome too :)

Here is what I'm trying to do :

**Code example**

```
Promise = require 'bluebird'
Model = Promise.promisifyAll(require '[...]') # mongoose model promisified

getOpts = () -> [...] # whatever

Promise.each [1..3], (number) ->
  opts = getOpts(number)
  return Model.count(opts).exec (err, count) ->
    return "the count is #{count}"
.spread () ->
  console.log JSON.stringify arguments
  result = arguments.join(',')
  [...]
```

**Explanations**

I want to run the same function with `1`, `2`, `3` (sequentially), so I use bluebird's `.each` function.
In the function, I need to get a count from my database. I'm using `mongoose` with bluebird's `promisifyAll` function to return a Promise and make sure that `.each` waits until each query is done to go next.

Then, I would like to gather the result of each query. I'm using bluebird's `spread` to gather the return values of `.each`. However, it doesn't contain the return value of the nested promise. `arguments` value is :

```
{
  "0": 1,
  "1": 2,
  "2": 3
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Looks like bluebird's `.each` doesn't go well with `.spread`. I'm investigating on this issue.

**EDIT 2**

(Thanks Bergi)

I found a solution : first I build an array of functions. Then I call bluebird's `.all` on this array, and then `.spread`.

**EDIT 3**

Ok, I finally tried `.map` instead of `.each` and it works great also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like bluebird's `.each` doesn't go well with `.spread`

Yes indeed. `each` does return a promise for an array, if you want to use that *array* just use `then`:

```
Promise.each [1..3], (number) ->
  opts = getOpts(number)
  Model.countAsync(opts).then (count) ->
    "the count is #{count}"
.then (args) ->
  console.log JSON.stringify args
  result = args.join(',')
  […]
```

`spread` is only for callback functions that want to use an individual variable (function parameter) for every array element, like `.spread (firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult) -> …`.

Also, `arguments` is an array-like object, not a true array, that's why you get that odd JSON representation and why the `.join` call does throw an exception.

> However, it doesn't contain the return value of the nested promise

Yes, `each` was thought for side effects only originally, and instead of collecting results it returns the original input. This will change with version 3.0. Until then, you can use `map`. See [Bluebird: getting the results of each()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29818688/1048572) for further details.